# why do some research articles not have issue number?

Tags: publications, citations

How can I get the information for issue number for this article?

I am trying to cite this article
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S004060901300117X?via%3Dihub

doi: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tsf.2013.01.016

this is what I got from doi2bib.org:

```
@article{Taylor2013,
  doi = {10.1016/j.tsf.2013.01.016},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tsf.2013.01.016},
  year = {2013},
  month = mar,
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
  volume = {531},
  pages = {354--361},
  author = {A.A. Taylor and M.J. Cordill and L. Bowles and J. Schalko and G. Dehm},
  title = {An elevated temperature study of a Ti adhesion layer on polyimide},
  journal = {Thin Solid Films}
}
```

Comment: Clicking on the volume number for this paper at the web page you gave for the paper itself, I was led to [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/thin-solid-films/vol/531/suppl/C), which strongly suggests to me that for this journal (and at this time; may have been different 10 or 20 years ago) a volume is not separated into different issues.

Comment: do you have any idea about `suppl/C` in the link?
https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/thin-solid-films/vol/531/suppl/C.

for now, I put `supplement C` in `issue` field.

Comment: I get what looks like the same content when I remove /suppl/C from the URL, so I have not idea what "suppl/C" is. However, I don't think "suppl/C" should be used for an issue designation. If you go [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/thin-solid-films/issues?page=2) and click on "1981 --- Volumes 75-86", you'll see that, in the earlier years of this journal, issue numbers were used, but it appears they were phased out sometime in the early to mid 2000s.

Comment: yes, there are some variations even after 2000s. 
so, should I write `--`, or leave it empty, or any other idea?

Comment: Maybe just ask the journal when you submit your article? All my references were just typed directly in, and I simply followed the style of the journal (italicize paper titles or italicize journal titles?, etc.), but I haven't submitted anything in the past decade or so. In fact, my present style (for informal posting on the internet) has evolved into giving full names, full journal titles, volume/issue and date as precise as I can determine, etc. as [in these examples](https://mathoverflow.net/a/301401/15780), but I don't know whether you have this freedom.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro is correct - for Thin Solid Films each issue is its own separate volume. TSF isn't the only journal that does that these days either.